# Convert byte array to float 32bit and 64bit?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitconverter

How would you convert 4 bytes in a byte array to a 32-bit float? Then how would you do the same for 8 bytes in a byte array for a 64-bit float(double)? I noticed the BitConverter class in C# has this, however I am curious about the math behind it.

I've currently written quite a few byte conversion functions, although would it be more efficient to just use the BitConverter class instead of my own functions?

Answer (score 1):

It would usually be more efficient to use the `BitConverter` functions, although in some cases (for example, converting two bytes to a short) the code is a lot faster if you write an inline shift-and-or operation.

If in doubt, instrument the code with a `Stopwatch` and time a release build. It's the only way to know, really.

However, if you are dealing with *arrays* of values, then it can be quicker and easier (but at the expense of memory space) to convert the entire array from one type to another using `Buffer.BlockCopy`.

For example, you can copy an array of doubles to an array of bytes and back as follows:

```
double[] original = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
int byteCount = sizeof(double) * original.Length;

byte[] asBytes = new byte[byteCount];
Buffer.BlockCopy(original, 0, asBytes, 0, byteCount);

double[] copied = new double[original.Length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(asBytes, 0, copied, 0, byteCount);

foreach (double d in copied)
    Console.WriteLine(d);
```

This might be more suited to your particular scenario. As ever, you'd need to do some careful timings to be sure if it was useful.

Comment: I'm programming a server, so I am not sure if it'd be a great idea to user the block copy function when I could potentially have many connections and many packets going out and coming in.

Comment: The bit converter seems to have some problems for me though. The main one being I cannot specify the length of a string with the to string function. So how would I go about bit shifting into a 32/64 bit float manually?

Comment: @user3519915 What have strings to do with this?

Comment: Simple example explaining the lack of functionality of the bit converter.

Comment: @user3519915 I don't understand - a BitConverter is used to convert value types to/from arrays of bytes. Converting to/from strings is string formatting and parsing, an unrelated concept.